# Simple javascript variables question

Tags: javascript

Can anybody tell me why this line isn't working?

```
window.open('entertainers/drilldown.php?state=' + varlocation + '?p=','performers_frame')
```

I know it's simple, and I know iframes suck but i am not familiar with javascript variables.

Thanks in advance!

Ryan

Comment: there doesn't appear to be any jquery code here? what are you expecting in 'varlocation'?  are you actually getting an error?

Comment: What is varlocation defined as, if defined at all?

Comment: A hint in future: (1) What is it doing? (2) What is it meant to be doing? Just stating those two facts will make everyone's job here so much easier.

Comment: Why did someone upvote this?? lol :)

Comment: @HBoss, I would hope it's because my edits made it "useful and clear" :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing jQuery about that variable. If that's a jQuery wrapped set you'd need to show us the rest of the code or tell us what it represents so you can get the attribute you're looking for. You're not providing enough for us to help you.

**EDIT**:

Ryan, if the variable is defined as `$.varlocation` then you have to append it as that. Try this:

```
window.open('entertainers/drilldown.php?state=' + $.varlocation + '&p=','performers_frame')
```

Just because it is declared with a `$` doesn't mean it is a jQuery wrapped set. In this case, it isn't.

Comment: There's a comment section created purposly for these kind of statements, right under the question.

Comment: i swear i tried that, but i mustnt have. worked perfect. thanks

Comment: @Paolo, as bitingly funny as that sarcasm was, someone with close to 30k rep, such as yourself, should know that your original answer *wasn't* an answer at all, hence should have been in a comment. That's something Luca seems to have learned much quicker than you :-).

Comment: @Pax: I am willing to concede that the original answer was tiptoeing the line between a comment and an answer. I obviously know where things belong and if I posted it as an answer it's because it was my answer. He downvoted it, I added to it, it helped the OP, everyone's happy.

Answer (score 5):

should this `drilldown.php?state=' + varlocation + '?p=','performers_frame')`

be this

```
drilldown.php?state=' + varlocation + '&p=','performers_frame')
```

replacing the second ? with &